# Import a framework and make it available to subsequent imports

Tags: javascript, import, firebase-authentication

I'm using Webpack to compile my Javascript, which imports Firebase Authentication in index.js in the usual manner:

```
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth/cordova";
```

Because index.js was getting large and I wanted to organise some of my functions, I've spread code into subsequent Javascript files, such as 'morecode.js'

**morecode.js**

```
function FBauthTest() {
 // Perform Firebase functions, such as Authentication
   const auth = getAuth();
 };
export {FBauthTest};
```

**index.js**

```
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth/cordova";
import {FBauthTest} from "./modecode";
```

Beforehand, when all the code was in one file, all Firebase content worked fine.  But now, even though my index.js and morecode.js are getting compiled into a single index.min.js file (by Webpack), the FBauthTest function returns that it can't access the Firebase object.

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getAuth
```

So my question is, once you've imported a framework/library, what is the simplest way to make it available to subsequent imported Javascript code?